Cloudformation - API Gateway Invalid Resource identifier how to resolve?
[No other Q&A has resolved this for me!]
I have a cloudformation template I am using to build a stack containing a AWS API Gateway but keep running into the following error:
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid Resource identifier specified (Service: ApiGateway, Status Code: 404, Request ID: <snip>)" (RequestToken: <snip>, HandlerErrorCode: NotFound)

on the resource called MyApiAsyncResource (see below).
The API part of the template looks like this:
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: <snip>
Resources:
  MyApi:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Name: "MyRestApi"
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - REGIONAL

  MyApiResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      ParentId: !GetAtt MyApi.RootResourceId
      PathPart: 'app'
      RestApiId: !Ref MyApi

  MyApiDummyMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: "GET"
      ResourceId: !Ref MyApiAsyncResource
      RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
      AuthorizationType: "NONE"
      MethodResponses:
        - StatusCode: '200'

  MyApiAsyncResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      ParentId: !Ref MyApiResource
      PathPart: 'async'
      RestApiId: !Ref MyApi


which is intended to resolve to
GET .../prod/app/async
I've been stuck on this for some time now - what is the cause and how can I fix it?
Update: Here's the cloudtrail snippet:
    "userAgent": "cloudformation.amazonaws.com",
    "errorCode": "NotFoundException",
    "errorMessage": "Invalid Resource identifier specified",
    "requestParameters": {
        "parentId": "1p9c4w",
        "restApiId": "<snip>",
        "createResourceInput": {
            "pathPart": "async"
        },
        "template": false
    },

1p9c4w is the physical ID of MyApiResource. Perhaps that's the problem - that whatever it was is now gone. How do I update the reference to a living resource?

Did you try putting DependsOn in MyApiAsyncResource? It looks like CF is trying to create a MyApiAsyncResource while MyApiResource is still not completed

@Caldazar Unfortunately this gives the same error. I also tried creating MyApiResource alone, without any child resources, which did work. But as soon as I reintroduce MyApiAsyncResource on a subsequent deploy I get the error.. :\

@Caldazar I've added some cloudtrail context. Huge thanks for any and all assistance
